erosion control after ivy removal
Douglas Fir Root


slope 1

I have cut back some very old ivy on a west-facing steep (50°+) slope but many 3-4" thick roots remain, holding back the bank. I wonder whether I can just intersperse native plants and hope they'll smother any ivy that tries to return...or should I attempt to cover the slope with plastic to kill the roots? It's late spring and the sun beats down on the slope. Soil is very loose and rocky and it's impossible to water given the slope. I'm thinking low oregon grape, salal, and grasses. The location is Camano Island, north of Seattle. Thoughts?

where in the world are you located?  Can you add a picture?

Camano Island, north of Seattle. Don't see how to add photos here....

To add images click on the icon with two triangles and a little dot resembling a scenery.

I don't see said icon anywhere...screen shot?

Possibly another helpful post: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7825/are-there-some-plant-based-erosion-control-ground-cover-options-for-pacific-nort

all--wanted to thank the community for all the great input and give an update--today an arborist confirmed that the Doug Fir is healthy and at no risk and rather than building a rigid structure that its roots might impede, he suggested planting Shore Pine and native grasses right in the sandy bluff to stabilize.

@PollyHopkins That's a positive update!  Please come back with how it all works out, and maybe a picture, when your project is 'done' .

In rainy Washington I recommend a "Dirt Locker"
It's a modular retaining wall that can be made big as possible, fights erosion by being a network of mini dams. Water cascades from terrace to terrace.


It's far cheaper than rocks/bricks.

thank you for this! a friend on FB also recco'd this system and I think it'll work well. :-)

Ivy can be an absolute monster. However, if your aim is to prevent slope erosion, ivy can also be your friend. Why not just let the ivy regrow as a low ground coverer? Manage it by (a) keeping it within bounds, and (b) trimming it with a decent hedge trimmer once or twice a year.

Due to the deeply embedded roots I suspect that some ivy will be part of the slope control plan.

I think native plants will competing against English Ivy with established roots will need a little help.  That ivy is tenacious and patient.
I like your solarizing with plastic idea.  It will kill a lot of your soil's biome though.  It can recover of course, but something to consider.
Ideally you'd just pull the ivy roots out.  You don't have to get all of them for it to be productive, and it's not as much toil as it sounds like in loose soil.  Any children with idle hands around?
I think you would also be OK with leaving the roots as they are, so long as you understand you have a few years of casual but constant ivy weeding ahead of you.
For your erosion concern, you could mulch it heavily with wood chips.  This will stop the erosion, make any ivy that emerges obvious for you to remove, and does all the lovely mulch stuff for the new plants you will be planting.  You can even water a mulched slope, no problem.  It's extremely simple to 'un-do' when you have a better idea- just turn it into the soil.

my situation is pretty dire as the slope is crumbly and very steep (50+ degree slope?) and the huge ivy roots are partially wrapped around the roots of a Doug Fir that's right on the edge of the bank. I am investigating Dirt Locker system with the hopes that if we put weed blocker fabric under and enough dirt in each "locker" we can smother the ivy over time. eeek.

@PollyHopkins Oh wow that is steep.  Good luck with it!

i'll need it! Dirt Locker isn't recco'd for slopes >45degrees and I've got close to 90!

@PollyHopkins Now that I see your pictures, I'm reminded of straw erosion control mats I've seen on similarly steep slopes after construction.  They seem like they work well.  Please post a picture of whatever you end up doing, it looks like a fun project!

not sure "fun" is the right adjective, but i will surely update with photos when i figure this out!
